# How to draw shapes with OpenGl inside fragment instead of activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, opengl-es

I am using this instruction: https://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/environment.

But I have to work with fragment instead of activity. Also I have some picture on main fragment and using OpenGl I have to draw some shapes. But, when I start app in becomes just empty dark screen.
Somewhere I found that I can write something like this for fragment, but If I remove this line of code my xml layout become on app, but I need to mix fragment and draw shapes over this fragment.

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        lifecycle.addObserver(viewModel)
        val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false)

        val fL = rootView.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.main)
        customGLSurfaceView = CustomGLSurfaceView(requireContext())
        fL.addView(customGLSurfaceView) // this line
        return rootView
    }
```

Comment: It might be a problem with putting it in a ConstraintLayout without any LayoutParams. Try using a FrameLayout as the root element, and set LayoutParams with MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT on the GL view before adding it to the Frame Layout. Alternatively, don't inflate any xml root view at all, and simply return your GL surface view in `onCreateView`. And of course, if you don't start rendering to your GL surface, it will just be black.

Comment: @Tenfour04, I just need to keep camera on my main fragment and detect face and put some shapes on lips, for example. So case without inflating xml doesn't fit :(

Comment: At least give it the layout Params to match parent. How are you determining it isn’t working? You should clear the GL color to something other than black so you’ll know immediately if you can see the GL surface.

Comment: @Tenfour04, my screen becomes black and I can't see any xml items in fragment. 
So need to try to change color? Just to test.